# When people don't understand

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Over ten people visited [this thread](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22430/can-we-formally-define-the-golden-ratio?noredirect=1#comment51151_22430). One or two did not understand the question, why suppose that makes the question ununderstandable?

The system is set up to make difficult questions obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is set up to make users write clearly and concisely.

Over on Electronics.SE, I have done a lot of review work in the past. Even though for some of the questions I didn't know the answer or what exactly was meant, it's relatively easy to see whether a question is properly formulated or not.

Your question used to start with:

> EA, EB, A<=>B

Without explanation (which wasn't really there), this is meaningless. <=> can be interpreted as equivalence in logic, in geometry I'm not aware of a use of ⇔. You also wrote:

> i.e. does the golden ratio have two symbols and three definitions? Do any other shapes?

But the golden ratio is, well, a ratio, not a shape. So this question doesn't make sense either.

In your latest version these problems have been resolved. Still, it's unclear to me why this question is on this site and not on Math.SE.

Lastly, note that 5 votes are needed to close a question, and 5 other votes can reopen that question. If enough people understand your question, there is no problem.

Comment: i guess you are right with your last point, thanks :)